# Anyone else having a problem deleting comments?

Tags: support, comment, deletion

I am running Safari on a Mac. The last few days I have made some comments on questions or answers which I would normally simply have deleted, because they were dealt with. But every time I now go to try to delete, the site hangs on me and I have to refresh the screen.

Wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same, or whether there is a work-around.

Comment: If anything, in the last five and a half months, I've had *way* easier time deleting comments! :-)

Comment: Have you tried different browsers, different operating systems, different computers, different accounts?

Comment: Also, have you tried clear your cache (at least the part related to this site)? Because if there's one thing that is true on the internet is that [if it's not working, you should blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Safari 12.0.2, MacOS 10.14.2: Deleting a comment worked for me just now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for this. It works in Firefox, so I expect the cache thing is right